# Yii can't access session variables

Tags: php, session, yii

My problem: I can't access session data in the view, which I tried to save in the controller before rendering the view.
In my opinion there's an error when storing the session data. (It's necessary for me to modify the session data after creating it, not only in the single action.)

**ProcessController.php**

```
public function actionNew() {

    $formhash = md5(time());
    $hashList = array();
    $hashList[$formhash]['processingNumber'] = '';
    //fill with empty model
    $hashList[$formhash]['model'] = $this->loadModel();
    //store hashList in session
    Yii::app()->session['hashList'] = $hashList;

    $this->render('/process', array('hashValue => $formHash));
```

}

Now in the view I need the data from the session to show them to the user. But when dumping the hashList it just dumps "null" (Maybe because the saving in the controller didn't went well).

**process.php**

```
<?php
$form = this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'process_form',
    //several other things...
));
//Output: null
CVarDumper::dump(Yii::app()->session['hashList'],10,true);
?>
```

I tried to use $_SESSION instead of Yii::app()->session, which gives me access to the data in the view. But when handling other actions in the Controller the $_SESSION variable is undefined.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: @filla2003 Why do you save it into session anyway? Look at the bottom of my answer. You can just reach them into your view like you did it with `hashValue`.

Comment: can you provide the output of `var_dump(get_class(Yii:app()->session))` ? In both places of the code? This would be helpful.

Comment: Both places mean Controller and View? Both time the output is 'CHTttpSession'. Not sure if this helps you...

Comment: Btw...when using add/get/remove everything is working fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer is:

Regarding to this [documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession):

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
$session->open();
$value1=$session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'
$value2=$session['name2'];  // get session variable 'name2'
foreach($session as $name=>$value) // traverse all session variables
$session['name3']=$value3;  // set session variable 'name3'
```

You can use as well:

```
Yii::app()->session->set('hashList', $hashList);
Yii::app()->session->get('hashList');
```

And set it again.

Beside this session thing, why do not you use this:

```
$this->render('/process', array('hashValue => $formHash, 'hashList' => $hashList));
```

So you do not need to save it in a session if you can reach it directly into the view.

Comment: I'd like to store it in a session, because it's possible to have several tabs with different hashValues and in each tab I need the updated hashList.

Comment: This "long answer" does not answer the question. Also it is not true. The documentation you've linked explicitly states that the session data can be accessed like an array. When you are writing "You can use as well ... " you implicating that the code in the question is expected to work, what is not true.

Comment: What is not true? First part of this answer is 1:1 from the documents - so that must be true. And second part is how you use it everywhere else if you not created a session explicit. Reading the whole docs helps alot.

Comment: I mean you don't reflect the *real* problem. The documentation states that `ArrayAccess` is possible as well as `add/get`. Isn't it? This was clear before, you wasn't required to mention this again. So why does it not work in the example above? <-- This is the question.

Comment: The documentation states that ArrayAccess is possible if you create the session just a few lines above. The example above did not work because all the magic that happens in Yii.

Comment: You misunderstood the example! Read the [source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/CHttpSession.php#L486) and you'll see that this makes no sense. (I told that before) Both ways accessing the `$_SESSION` global directly.

Comment: I just tested it and you can use `Yii::app()->session['test'] = 'xxx'` and it will print out `xxx` if you call `Yii::app()->session->get('test')`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying :) So there must be another problem with @filla2003 's code

Comment: Well, I did it in the same script. In our project occurred something similar when we set it somewhere and called it on a totally different place. I asked my mate to get me an example.

Comment: Well, we can had this bug right now too - but with several tries we can not reproduce it. Sometimes it works and other times it does not work. And it does not matter if you save session to DB or not.

Comment: I'm sure the problem will happen with both ways - sometimes. This because they are actually doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation your code should work. An alternative might be to use the following, but it does **the same**:

```
Yii::app()->session->add('hashList', $hashList); // set the value
$hashList = Yii::app()->session->get('hashList'); // get the value
```

I expect the problem either a debugging problem, meaning you have observed cached or otherwise outdated data or a problem in parts of your code that you have not shown.

Comment: It's been working inside the view, but when being again in the controller the var_dump of Yii:app->session['hashList'] gives me null again.

Comment: @filla2003 according to [this documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#get-detail) you need something like  `Yii::app()->session->get('hashList')`.

Comment: @Jurik: yes this is working, but how can I change attributes inside the session after they are set once. Again using session->add?

Comment: @Juri I'm not sure with the importance of my answer anymore. I only see the source code of Yii at the moment. Having just this I would say using the ArrayAccess interface (`['foo'] = `) should work too. isn't it? `offsetSet/offsetGet` actually just duplicating(!) the code of `add/get`

Comment: @filla2003 first you've to [remove](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#remove-detail) it and set it again.

Comment: @hek2mgl I am not sure about the side effects, especially when you reset it. Of course you can use `unset(Yii::app()->session['hashList']` but that is not the intended way of working with Yii session functions.